# Why stored procedure return -1

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am very new with stored procedure.
I don't have more idea.

I am trying to insert data in my database using stored procedure.

If it exist it return 0 otherwise insert data and return 1.

So that I can print text on label that data inserted or data already exist.

It is returning -1 on every entry.

Here is my stored procedure. Is it not right ?

```
    USE [HRMS]
    GO
    /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[hrm_AddLanguages2]    Script Date:   05/02/2014 10:19:38 ******/
   SET ANSI_NULLS ON
   GO
  SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
  GO
  ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[hrm_AddLanguages2]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

    @Name varchar(120),
    @CreatedOn datetime,
    @UpdatedOn datetime=0,
    @CreatedBy bigint=0,
    @UpdatedBy bigint=0,
    @IsDeleted bit=0
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        DECLARE @ID int;
        SELECT @ID = coalesce((select max(ID) + 1 from Languages), 1)
    COMMIT   
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    IF EXISTS(SELECT Name FROM [dbo].[Languages] WHERE Name = @Name)
    Begin
    Return 0
    End
    Else
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Languages](Name, CreatedOn,UpdatedOn,CreatedBy,UpdatedBy,IsDeleted) VALUES(@Name,@CreatedOn,@UpdatedOn,@CreatedBy,@UpdatedBy,@IsDeleted)
        Return 1
END
```

Here is my Default.aspx.cs code-

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

if (Page.IsValid)
    {  
    btnAdd.Visible = true;
    btnDelete.Visible = true;
    Label2.Visible = true;
    tblAdd.Visible = false;
    int valueReturn = add();
    if (valueReturn == 1)
    {
        Label2.Text = "Successfully Added";
    }
    else
    {
        Label2.Text = "Already Exist";
    }
    }
    GridView1.DataBind();
    txtName.Text = "";
}

public int add()
{
    string strcon =  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Dbconnection"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(strcon);

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("hrm_AddLanguages2", sqlConnection);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtName.Text;
    command.Parameters.Add("@CreatedOn", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
    command.Parameters.Add("@UpdatedOn", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
    command.Parameters.Add("@CreatedBy", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = 1;
    command.Parameters.Add("@UpdatedBy", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = 1;
    command.Parameters.Add("@IsDeleted", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = 0;
    sqlConnection.Open();
    return command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Your insert is probably failing because you aren't passing the `@ID` which you've just worked out. But the MAX+1 strategy isn't a good idea IMO (despite wrapping it in a transaction :-)- rather use an `IDENTITY`.

Comment: id is auto generating. i am checking if name not exists then insert

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using ExecuteNonQuery in your Default.aspx

ExecuteNonQuery returns -1 if no records affected by your query.

Here you have set nocounton in your stored procedure. That's why in your executenonquery no records affected value( means -1) is coming.

Set your count on you will get desired result.

You can go through below link for more details-

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/01/27/sqlcommand-executenonquery-returns-1-when-doing-insert-update-delete.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The same thing applies with Insert,update and Delete. If you SET NOCOUNT ON, then the integer that would normally be returned by executing the query will always be -1. You have forced it to always return false because you have SET NOCOUNT ON.This is why it is common to SET NOCOUNT ON when doing an insert. When doing an insert, the return value you are interested in is usually the ID of the newly inserted article, not the number of rows affected.

Tips.

1. It is generally okay to SET NOCOUNT ON for inserts if you are returning the ID of the newly inserted item.
2. For updates and deletes, you should not SET NOCOUNT ON. You should let the sproc return the number of rows affected.

Comment: I have written in stored procedure if exists then return 0 else 1. Is it not going in if else block?

Comment: Yes it is going to else part and successfully executed as you have set "SET NOCOUNT ON" ,that's why it return -1. You can set the NONCOUNT to OFF  before IF.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a mapping error, check if there is a class that reflect the return type of the sp, if not you need to create one.

Example of usage

```
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386975.aspx
```