# Passing and return values from stored procedure to view model

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, asp.net-core-mvc, viewmodel

In advance, I appreciate there are lots of stored procedure related questions and answers out there on Stackoverflow, I know because over the last few days I have read a tonne of them but I still cannot get my head around the process of creating a stored procedure that will return values to my view model.

This question is in two parts:

1. Why does my code not successfully run and instead returns -1 ?
2. If with your help I get past that first issue how do I then get the returned data from the stored procedure into a list of my view model

I very much appreciate any help the community can give me...

- DB name is `Discovery`
- Table name is `Person`
- Stored procedure name is `uspGetOrgChart`

My table

```
CREATE TABLE Discovery.dbo.Person 
(
     ADID nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
     First_Name nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
     Last_Name nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
     Report_To_ADID nvarchar(50) NULL,
     Position_ID int NULL,
     Role_ID int NULL,
     IGEMS nvarchar(50) NULL,
     DOB date NULL,
     Start_Date date NULL,
     Cost_Code nvarchar(50) NULL,

     PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ADID),
     CONSTRAINT FK_Person_Position1 
         FOREIGN KEY (Position_ID) REFERENCES dbo.Position (Position_ID),
     CONSTRAINT FK_Person_Role 
         FOREIGN KEY (Role_ID) REFERENCES dbo.Role (Role_ID)
)
ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

My stored procedure is currently as follows:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspGetOrgChart]
    @ContactID VARCHAR(100) = 'NOE1WWD'
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --grab id of @contactid
    DECLARE @Test varchar(36)
    SELECT @Test = (SELECT ADID FROM Person c1 WHERE c1.ADID = @ContactID)

    ;WITH StaffTree AS 
    ( 
        SELECT  
            c.ADID, 
            c.First_Name, 
            c.Last_Name,
            c.Report_To_ADID, 
            c.Report_To_ADID as Manager_ID,
            cc.First_Name AS Manager_First_Name, 
            cc.Last_Name as Manager_Last_Name, 
            cc.First_name + ' ' + cc.Last_name AS [ReportsTo], 
            c.First_Name + ' ' + c.Last_Name as EmployeeName,  
            1 AS LevelOf 
        FROM 
            Person c 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            Person cc ON c.Report_To_ADID = cc.ADID 
        WHERE 
            c.ADID = @Test 
            OR (@Test IS NULL AND c.Report_To_ADID IS NULL) 

        UNION ALL 

        SELECT  
            s.ADID, 
            s.First_Name, 
            s.Last_Name, 
            s.Report_To_ADID, 
            t.ADID, 
            t.First_Name, 
            t.Last_Name, 
            t.First_Name + ' ' + t.Last_Name, 
            s.First_Name + ' ' + s.Last_Name,
            t.LevelOf + 1 
        FROM 
            StaffTree t 
        INNER JOIN 
            Person s ON t.ADID = s.Report_To_ADID 
        WHERE 
            s.Report_To_ADID = @Test 
            OR @Test IS NULL 
            OR t.LevelOf > 1 
    )
    SELECT * FROM StaffTree 
END
```

I have tested and the Procedure above works as I expected and returns the following columns:

```
 ADID    
 First_Name
 Last_Name
 Report_To_ADID
 Manager_ID
 Manager_First_Name
 Manager_Last_Name
 ReportsTo
 EmployeeName
 LevelOf
```

My view model is called `vmNewOrgChart`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Discovery.ViewModels
{
    public class vmNewOrgChart
    {
        public string ADID { get; set; }
        public string First_Name { get; set; }
        public string Last_Name { get; set; }
        public string Report_To_Adid { get; set; }
        public string Manager_ID { get; set; }
        public string Manager_First_Name { get; set; }
        public string Manager_Last_Name { get; set; }
        public string ReportsTo { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public int LevelOf { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is where I start to get completely stuck

```
public IActionResult Orgchart(string id)
{
    var personIdParam = new SqlParameter("@ContactID", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    personIdParam.Value = id;

    var result = _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec uspGetOrgChart", personIdParam);
}
```

The code above runs but the value of result is -1 which means it returned nothing or some error?

Many thanks for any assistance

Derek

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: A stored procedure returns `-1` if no rows affected (because you're using `SET NOCOUNT ON`, related issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23421356/why-stored-procedure-return-1)). If you want to project the result into a model class, use `_context.Database.SqlQuery<TResult>("exec uspGetOrgChart", personIdParam);` instead.

Comment: I am using SQLServer, the management sofwatre I am using is MS SQL Studio

Comment: why don't you use a function with table result and make a select on it? Something like this: _context.Database.SqlQuery<User>( 
                       "SELECT Name, Login FROM Users()").ToList(); 
More info about these funtions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440308/tsql-returning-a-table-from-a-function-or-store-procedure

Answer (score 0):

[`Database.ExecuteSqlCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand(v=vs.113).aspx) method usually used for executing action DML queries (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE`), which returns number of affected rows from those operations. If you want to return `SELECT` query results into designated model class, you should use [`Database.SqlQuery<TElement>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery(v=vs.113).aspx) with target model class set as type parameter like this:

```
_context.Database.SqlQuery<vmNewOrgChart>("exec uspGetOrgChart", personIdParam);
```

**Note:** By default if no records/rows affected with `ExecuteSqlCommand`, it returns `-1` value.

Additional reference: [Executing Raw SQL Queries Using Entity Framework](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/fbc96859-8a31-4735-baeb-7adcbc521b30.aspx)

**Update:**

For Entity Framework Core the `Database.SqlQuery<TElement>` is not available, you can use `DbSet.FromSql` or use `Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand()` as in example below:

```
using (var context = new DataContext())
{
    using (var cmd = context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "exec uspGetOrgChart";
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        var personIdParam = cmd.CreateParameter();
        personIdParam.ParameterName = "ContactID";
        personIdParam.Value = id;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(personIdParam);

        context.Database.OpenConnection();
        using (var result = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (result.HasRows)
            {
                // do something with results
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Related issues:

[How to run stored procedures in Entity Framework Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28599404/how-to-run-stored-procedures-in-entity-framework-core)

[Database.SqlQuery Missing](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10365)

Comment: Thank you for the reponse and help so far, it seems I may be doing semething out of context because I do not have the SqlQuery method available to me, am I missing a reference perhaps?

Comment: If you are using EntityFramework and your context is extending DbContext class you should see it as a method of Database property. May be that your intellisense is gone. Try to open and close vs.

Answer (score 0):

A procedure can't return a table. Use instead function with table return value:

```
CREATE FUNCTION  fnGetOrgChart()
RETURNS  @rtnTable TABLE 
(
---you fields
)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @TempTable table (id uniqueidentifier, name nvarchar(255)....)
insert into @myTable 
select from your stuff
--This select returns data
insert into @rtnTable
SELECT ID, name FROM @mytable 
return
END
```

See microsoft doc about function with table result

Then call

```
var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<vmNewOrgChart>("select * from fnGetOrgChart()");
```

as suggested by Tetsuya Yamamoto

Otherwise you must call the stored to fill a temp table then select data from the temp table and flush it

NB. You can easly pass parameters to these function. Omitted for brevity

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all so far

Thank you this is looking much closer to working. when i use the code

```
using (_context)
{
using (var cmd = _context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
{
cmd.CommandText = "exec uspGetOrgChart";
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

var personIdParam = cmd.CreateParameter();
personIdParam.ParameterName = "ContactID";
personIdParam.Value = id;

cmd.Parameters.Add(personIdParam);

_context.Database.OpenConnection();
using (var result = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
if (result.HasRows)
{
// do something with results

}
}
}

}
```

I get an error that the stored procedure cannot be found from this line, the procedure is definately there and working

```
(var result = cmd.ExecuteReader())
```

I thought this was because the code was closing and openning a second connection so I commented out the line

```
_context.Database.OpenConnection();
```

This resulted in an error that the connection was not open.

my current context is called

```
_Context
```

and is being used throughout the rest of the application, do I really have to create an entirely new context and connection in order to run the procedure.

Thanks
Derek

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your assistance I managed to get the Sproc to run successfully using this code

```
using (_context)
{
                using (var cmd = _context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "uspGetOrgChart";
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    var personIdParam = cmd.CreateParameter();
                    personIdParam.ParameterName = "ContactID";
                    personIdParam.Value = id;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add(personIdParam);

                    _context.Database.OpenConnection();
                    using (var result = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (result.HasRows)
                        {
                            // do something with results

                        }
                    }
                }

            }
```

The "exec" is not required in the commandtext

Answer (score 0):

you can use this solution :

```
 using (var cmd = _db.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "dbo.GetCategories"; //sp name
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    _db.Database.OpenConnection();
                    using (var result = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (result.HasRows)
                        {
                             var List= MapToList<Category>(result);
                        }
                    }
                }

public IList<T> MapToList<T>(DbDataReader dr)
        {
            var objList = new List<T>();
            var props = typeof(T).GetRuntimeProperties();

            var colMapping = dr.GetColumnSchema()
                .Where(x => props.Any(y => y.Name.ToLower() == x.ColumnName.ToLower()))
                .ToDictionary(key => key.ColumnName.ToLower());

            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    T obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
                    foreach (var prop in props)
                    {
                        if (colMapping.Any(a => a.Key.ToLower() == prop.Name.ToLower()))
                        {
                            var val = dr.GetValue(colMapping[prop.Name.ToLower()].ColumnOrdinal.Value);
                            prop.SetValue(obj, val == DBNull.Value ? null : val);
                        }
                    }
                    objList.Add(obj);
                }
            }
            return objList;
        }
```

Comment: i try to call store procedure in entity framework core . in using section i call stored procedure . This sp return the list of category model and MapToList method map the result to the Category class